# Yii 1.x, query in query DB selection

Tags: php, yii, phpactiverecord

I have such sql query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_role WHERE 
tbl_role.id NOT IN (
     SELECT tbl_user_role.roleID FROM tbl_user_role 
     WHERE tbl_user_role.userID = 35
)
AND
tbl_role.id NOT IN (
     SELECT tbl_user_role_request.roleID FROM tbl_user_role_request 
     WHERE tbl_user_role_request.userID = 35 AND tbl_user_role_request.dateEnd IS NULL)
```

What is the best solution to make it in Yii-like code. How can i do this query using Yii 1.x ?

Comment: what are you going to do with the result of the query?

Comment: @jagsler use in `CActiveForm` widget in `dropDownList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- tbl_role has a model named Role
- tbl_user_role has a model named UserRole
- tbl_user_role_request has a model named UserRoleRequest

Note that this will do 3 seperate queries but I believe this is the closest you can get without creating a total mess.

```
<?php

$userId = 35;

$roles = UserRole::findAllByCondition(array('userId' => $userId));
$roleIds = array_values(CHtml::listData($roles, 'roleId', 'roleId');

$roleRequests = UserRoleRequest::findAllByCondition(array('userId'=>$userId, 'dateEnd'=>null));
$roleRequestIds = array_values(CHtml::listData($roleRequest, 'roleId', 'roleId'));

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addNotInCondition('id', $roleIds);
$criteria->addNotInCondition('id', $roleRequestIds);

$roles = Role::findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CDbCommand`: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryAll-detail

Use the following code to fetch the data

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('sql query')->queryAll;
```

And then you can use this dataset to create the dropDownList

```
$list = CHtml::listData($data, 'value field', 'text field');
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'attribute', $list);
```

Comment: Query builder, yeah but i wonder can i create it like doctrine2? with ->leftJoin(), ->andWhere() etc.